# SVM and quadratic programming

Tags: quadratic-programming

I wonder if the SVM optimization problem 

minimize $||w||^2$
with the contraints $y_i(w^\intercal x_i+b)\ge 1$
could be formulated as a typical quadratic programming problem:
$0.5\cdot z^\intercal Mz$
with $Az\leq d$ and setting z to the vector $\left (\begin{array}{l}w_1\\\ldots\\w_n\\b\end{array} \right )$. 
The expression $||w||^2$ can be obtained by setting $M$ to $I$.

There is only one problem, $b$ doesnt show up in the objective function.
so i would have to introduce a zero line in $M$ but then it isn't invertible any more. Should I take the pseudo-inverse instead? Thanks for any hints.

Comment: SVM does reduce to a QP problem in the dual form.  There are plenty of resources out there to explain it.  To handle b you would add a 1 line, not a zero line.

Comment: a thanks a lot for the answer, do you know some resource where this is stated maybe?  Actually I am not 100% convinced of the solution.

Comment: Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie et al is one. Pretty much any book that covers SVM's will have it though.

Comment: Adding a rows of 1 to matrix M, as @Tpofofn states doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is to to let $z=(w_1,\ldots,w_n,b)^\intercal$, to set $M$ to

$$M = [I_{n\times n} 0_{n\times 1}; 0_{(n+1)\times (n+1)}].$$

and to stack a column of $1$'s in the last column of $A$.

Then solve via a QP solver.